# InputSimulator in a background process?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a small web server written in C# hosted on my PC. When I access certain URLs at this server, I want to press certain media keys such as play/pause, next track, previous track.

I found InputSimulator to be useful and easy to use, but it seems to work only when the  server process is in the foreground. Is there any way to use this class when the process is in the background?

**Edit:**
I read about PostMessage, but that interface requires a process to send the button presses to. Would sending a media key event, e.g. play/pause, to my server process cause, say, Spotify to play/pause?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Autoit](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/). It allows sending the keypress or control commands for inactive process.